# Cocoa -/+ declarations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What's the difference between - and + when declaring with Cocoa/Obj-C.

e.g.
    `-(void)doSomething{}`
or
    `+(void)doSomething{}`

Comment: Of course the real answer to this is don't try to learn Cocoa by asking the uttermost basic questions on Stack Overflow. Buy a good book and work through it; you won't regret it.

Answer (score 12):

"`-`" means an *instance* method (meaning relative to a specific object), while "`+`" means a *class* method (meaning usable by a class in general—it doesn't have to be tied to a specific object).

Example:

For "`- (void)doSomething`":

```
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[obj doSomething];
```

vs

```
[MyClass doSomething];
```

for "`+ (void)doSomething`".

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a little analogy to htw's answer:

- + is for what a static method would be in C++, C# or Java
- - is for what a non-static (regular) method would be in C++, C# of Java